# Error when converting a pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pandas

I can't figure out how to convert a pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame.

Here is an example of what my data looks like using df.head():

```
    crash_date.             crash_time  latitude    longitude   location    
0   2019-06-15T00:00:00.000 14:57       40.8146250  -73.9203600 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-73.92036, 40.8146250]
1   2019-07-03T00:00:00.000 0:50        40.8295970  -73.9022450 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-73.902245, 40.8295970]   
2   2019-06-24T00:00:00.000 16:45       40.7054600  -73.7949000 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-73.7949, 40.7054600]
3   2019-06-16T00:00:00.000 3:25        40.7128030  -73.9541700 {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-73.95417, 40.7128030]
```

I tried converting it:

```
geometry = geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude)
df = df.drop(['longitude', 'latitude'], axis=1)
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-6090c239d222> in <module>
----> 1 geometry = geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude)
      2 df = df.drop(['longitude', 'latitude'], axis=1)
      3 crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
      4 gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
      5 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in _points_from_xy(x, y, z)
    190         geom = [shapely.geometry.Point(i, j, k) for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z)]
    191     else:
--> 192         geom = [shapely.geometry.Point(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y)]
    193     return geom
    194 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    190         geom = [shapely.geometry.Point(i, j, k) for i, j, k in zip(x, y, z)]
    191     else:
--> 192         geom = [shapely.geometry.Point(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y)]
    193     return geom
    194 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/point.py in __init__(self, *args)
     47         BaseGeometry.__init__(self)
     48         if len(args) > 0:
---> 49             self._set_coords(*args)
     50 
     51     # Coordinate getters and setters

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/point.py in _set_coords(self, *args)
    130             self._geom, self._ndim = geos_point_from_py(args[0])
    131         else:
--> 132             self._geom, self._ndim = geos_point_from_py(tuple(args))
    133 
    134     coords = property(BaseGeometry._get_coords, _set_coords)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapely/geometry/point.py in geos_point_from_py(ob, update_geom, update_ndim)
    207         coords = ob
    208     n = len(coords)
--> 209     dx = c_double(coords[0])
    210     dy = c_double(coords[1])
    211     dz = None

TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

df.info() shows:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1000 entries, 0 to 999
Data columns (total 29 columns):
crash_date                       1000 non-null object
crash_time                       1000 non-null object
borough                          620 non-null object
zip_code                         620 non-null object
latitude                         900 non-null object
longitude                        900 non-null object
location                         900 non-null object
on_street_name                   782 non-null object
off_street_name                  491 non-null object
number_of_persons_injured        1000 non-null object
number_of_persons_killed         1000 non-null object
number_of_pedestrians_injured    1000 non-null object
number_of_pedestrians_killed     1000 non-null object
number_of_cyclist_injured        1000 non-null object
number_of_cyclist_killed         1000 non-null object
number_of_motorist_injured       1000 non-null object
number_of_motorist_killed        1000 non-null object
contributing_factor_vehicle_1    994 non-null object
contributing_factor_vehicle_2    865 non-null object
collision_id                     1000 non-null object
vehicle_type_code1               993 non-null object
vehicle_type_code2               812 non-null object
contributing_factor_vehicle_3    61 non-null object
contributing_factor_vehicle_4    23 non-null object
contributing_factor_vehicle_5    7 non-null object
vehicle_type_code_3              59 non-null object
vehicle_type_code_4              23 non-null object
vehicle_type_code_5              7 non-null object
cross_street_name                218 non-null object
dtypes: object(29)
memory usage: 226.7+ KB
```

Changed first line per recommendation

```
geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude.values.astype('float32'), df.latitude.values.astype('float32'))
df = df.drop(['longitude', 'latitude'], axis=1)
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
```

Error message now shows:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'longitude'
```

Answer (score 7):

Your lon, lat cols are object types. [Cast](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) them to floats:

```
geometry = geopandas.points_from_xy(df.longitude.astype('float32'), df.latitude.astype('float32'))
#OR
geometry = geopandas.points_from_xy(df['longitude'].astype('float32'), df['latitude'].astype('float32'))
```

Comment: It's showing a different error now:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'longitude'

Comment: @jon Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If it's a different error then that may be best asked as a new question.

Comment: Make sure you're running that before you run `df = df.drop(['longitude', 'latitude'], axis=1)` and try `df['longitude'].astype('float32'), df['latitude'].astype('float32')`